# What does this vulgar expression mean?

Tags: idioms, formality, offensive-language

I found several mentions, only online, and have no idea what this means. But obviously people repeat this phrase, so they mean something particular.

Here is one example:

> It is still morning here so we have to have coffee cake. And I think a variety of coffee cake/pastry is OK. It's just can I have tea instead of coffee?
>
> Guess you just woke up with **a case of fuck-arounds**.
>
> Wow. You're a dick.
>
> But I love coffee cake...

Then, there is a Twitter message:

> Patty woke up with **a bad case of fuck arounds**...

Then there is this Reddit message:

> Guess you just woke up with **a case of fuck-arounds**.

Facebook has a message:

> I woke this morning with **a case of fuck arounds**

Then, another web site has this message:

> Black Hippy shit, got the **case of fuck arounds**.

Now, after I post, this page will add to the popularity of this phrase.

(Reminds me of quantum mechanics, when one can't measure something without affecting that same thing to some degree, modifying its state.)

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the+fuck+arounds

Comment: It means anything you want.  It's just another fuck construction, the meanings of which change subtilely.  I wouldn't use it outside a group.  Can't wait to hear what people think it means.

Comment: I presume it's a variation of "fucking around," the vulgar version of [putter around](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/putter).

Comment: If you also ask about: *its origin*, or *where/who coined it*; or *when was it first used/heard*; or if the expression "a case of" is part of a meme etc. I guarantee you'll get some answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS SD2 notes, "to fuck around" means to putter, dither, do random ineffectual things.  "The fuck arounds" is a nominalization.  If you wake up with them, then you are going to fuck around and thereby abandon anything you planned to do or anything unplanned but useful.

This reminds me too of quantum mechanics, in that people using twitter, reddit, and random websites are, like Schrödinger's cat in a superimposed state of being brain dead and alive.  It's only when you query them does their brain state collapse.